# Euro sign (€) is rendered as Û, only on iPhone

Tags: html, character-encoding, euro

I stumbled upon this very weird issue: I have a plain HTML-document (having `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the head) containing a price list in Euro, thus showing prices with a Euro sign (€).
No rocket science involved.

The page looks fine in every common browser and on every screen. Except for Safari on iPhone. In that browser in particular, the `€` characters are rendered as `Û`.

And now for the bonus: when rendering the exact same page in Safari on macOS, in mobile (responsive) view with iPhone Safari as user agent, the € signs are showing as expected.

Yes, I already checked the Content-Type in the HTTP Response. That is, as expected: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`.

It makes no difference in the iPhone output when using these variants in the html:

```
€ 
&euro; 
&#128; 
&#0128;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case; here's a Python proof: `'€'.encode('mac_roman').decode('cp1252')` returns `'Û'`. BTW, Html numeric entities for the *Euro Sign* should be `&#8364;` or `&#x20ac;`.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that there was a `.woff` font type in the CSS, which looks like to be the preferred font type for Safari on a (physical!) iPhone. And apparently, this font type did not contain the Euro character, resulting in the rendering of an unexpected `Û`.

After removing this one faulty `.woff` font type, the issue was solved (this font was already listed with other file types as fallback as well, including `.eot`, `.ttf` and `.svg`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove both the `.woff` and `.woff2` font types in your CSS.